# Android Dev - Cant understand my logcat

Tags: eclipse, android-layout, android-intent, sdk, logcat

I really don't know how to solve that runtime execution of my Eclipse + Android SDK Project.

The minimum SDK target is 8(android 2.2) and TargetSDKVersion is 22(5.1 I think).

I suppose there is a problem with the project "appcompat_v7" but I don't know what it is and yesterday the app (in the project "Morphion") was running like I want. 
Also yesterday I don't notify this project(appcompat_v7) was automatically added(but maybe is was already here, I just dont remember).

And now it is here and it cause problems.

My Logcat show my this, but eclipse dont show errors on my code.

Thanks in advance and best regards,

```
04-06 20:01:38.272: I/dalvikvm(3810): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
04-06 20:01:38.272: W/dalvikvm(3810): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12206: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
04-06 20:01:38.272: D/dalvikvm(3810): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
04-06 20:01:38.272: I/dalvikvm(3810): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
04-06 20:01:38.272: W/dalvikvm(3810): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12212: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
04-06 20:01:38.272: D/dalvikvm(3810): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
04-06 20:01:38.272: I/dalvikvm(3810): Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
04-06 20:01:38.272: W/dalvikvm(3810): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9777: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
04-06 20:01:38.272: D/dalvikvm(3810): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
04-06 20:01:38.282: I/dalvikvm(3810): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
04-06 20:01:38.282: W/dalvikvm(3810): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 392: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
04-06 20:01:38.282: D/dalvikvm(3810): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-06 20:01:38.282: I/dalvikvm(3810): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
04-06 20:01:38.282: W/dalvikvm(3810): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 414: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
04-06 20:01:38.282: D/dalvikvm(3810): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-06 20:01:38.292: I/dalvikvm(3810): Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
04-06 20:01:38.292: W/dalvikvm(3810): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 355: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
04-06 20:01:38.292: D/dalvikvm(3810): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-06 20:01:38.292: I/dalvikvm(3810): Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
04-06 20:01:38.292: W/dalvikvm(3810): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 357: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
04-06 20:01:38.292: D/dalvikvm(3810): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-06 20:01:38.352: D/AndroidRuntime(3810): Shutting down VM
04-06 20:01:38.352: W/dalvikvm(3810): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4153d8b0)
04-06 20:01:38.362: E/AndroidRuntime(3810): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 20:01:38.362: E/AndroidRuntime(3810): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ppable.morphion/com.ppable.morphion.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-06 20:01:38.362: E/AndroidRuntime(3810):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
04-06 20:01:38.362: E/AndroidRuntime(3810):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
04-06 20:01:38.362: E/AndroidRuntime(3810):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
04-06 20:01:38.362: E/AndroidRuntime(3810):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
04-06 20:01:38.362: E/AndroidRuntime(3810):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-06 20:01:38.362: E/AndroidRuntime(3810):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
04-06 20:01:38.362: E/AndroidRuntime(3810):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
04-06 20:01:38.362: E/AndroidRuntime(3810):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 20:01:38.362: E/AndroidRuntime(3810):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-06 20:01:38.362: E/AndroidRuntime(3810):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
04-06 20:01:38.362: E/AndroidRuntime(3810):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
04-06 20:01:38.362: E/AndroidRuntime(3810):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-06 20:01:38.362: E/AndroidRuntime(3810): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-06 20:01:38.362: E/AndroidRuntime(3810):     at com.ppable.morphion.MainActivity.bindEventsListenerOnButtons(MainActivity.java:46)
04-06 20:01:38.362: E/AndroidRuntime(3810):     at com.ppable.morphion.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
04-06 20:01:38.362: E/AndroidRuntime(3810):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
04-06 20:01:38.362: E/AndroidRuntime(3810):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-06 20:01:38.362: E/AndroidRuntime(3810):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-06 20:01:38.362: E/AndroidRuntime(3810):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: I solved my problem.
Yes I was notify this but can't understand. But Finally I start ask me question.

What does it mean ( java.lang.NullPointerException ) ? 

Answer : surely that I try to manipulate an Object, that return NULL, with a method ( because it not initialized or I forgot to initialized it. Like : myObject.toString() , or in my case : replayButton.setOnClickListener(replayListener) )

And in effect it was that I was declared an object but I don't initialized it, and try to manipulated it... Shame :

replayButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bReplay); <-- and my app run like I want.